# iOS: Multi-Threading issues when loading sounds in the background

Tags: objective-c, ios, concurrency, avaudioplayer, objective-c-blocks

I have inherited some code that is in need of a bit of a tidy up. The app has a handful of core sounds and currently, there are lots of `AVAudioPlayer` instances attached to various `ViewController`'s all playing the same few sounds.

As part of the refactoring exercise, I have decided to implement a singleton class called `SoundController`. This class will contain one `AVAudioPlayer` for each sound that needs playing, and instead of each `ViewController` instantiating their own, they can easily make use of just the one:

```
[[SoundController controller].majorFunctionSound playAtTime:0];
```

Another important thing is to ensure that prepareToPlay: has been called on all the sounds prior to them being used to minimise any delays. Since there are only a handful of sounds and they are all likely to be used during any user session, it makes sense to preload all the sounds (on a background thread) when SoundController is first instantiated. In the init method I have something like this:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, nil, ^(void)          
{
NSURL *soundURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/MAJOR FUNCTION.m4a", [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath]]];
_majorAudioSound = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:soundURL error:nil];
[_majorAudioSound  prepareToPlay];
});
```

majorAudioSound is `(readonly, strong)`. `@synthesize majorAudioSound = _majorAudioSound`.

My concerns are around how poorly (or well) this is going to work in terms of concurrency and what I can do to improve the code. Specifically, if I do this:

```
[[SoundController controller].majorFunctionSound playAtTime:0];
```

There is clearly a chance that majorFunctionSound wont be initiated properly depending on whether the background initialisation block has completed yet. Is the worse that could happen that the property returns `nil` and the sound simply doesn't play?

What other issues might there be? Is there a way to always ensure that the AVAudioPlayer has been properly set up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I want you to think a second thought on whether your class have to be a singleton just because you intend to only have one instance of it. It is of course one way to do it, but I think that your initialization issues inherits from the fact that you decided to use a singleton class.

Lets say you have a class called SoundManager and you have made it a Singleton class.

When you ask for the instance of the SoundManager anywhere in your app, you will want to assume that the returned instance is ready to be used immediately. If you inside your SoundManager have an init method that is asynchronous, then you do have a design issue, since you should never have to know when you ask for a Singleton if it is the first time or not it has been initialized.

Since the SoundManager requires initialization I would let my app have an instance of the SoundManager in some kind of base class that takes care of the applications flow, instead of making it a Singleton. Either you could just let your AppDelegate instantiate the one and only SoundManager, or you could have a class called ApplicationController or something where you load all the stuff you need for the app when it initializes. Then you can reach the SoundManager instance via this controller class by passing a reference or by letting your ApplicationController be a singleton. Of course this also works if SoundManager is singleton, as long as you make sure you initialize it on startup, but I prefer to have as few singleton classes as possible.

Now to your question about knowing if your sounds are loaded or not.

I would recommend that you load all sounds before you let the user start using the app. In the meanwhile you could show something to the user, like a loading screen, a progressbar, and play sounds/music if you wish. Here is an example of a structure:

- Create a class called SoundManager with a property "loaded" that is false from start
- Create a class called ApplicationController that instantiate the SoundManager, and other useful classes you might have, like TextureManager or LocationManager etc.
- When the app starts, instantiate ApplicationController, which in turn instantiates SoundManager.
- Show a loading screen
- Let SoundManager load the "loading sound" first and once it is loaded, start playing it
- When the loading of sounds is completed, set the "loaded" property to true
- When ApplicationController has loaded everything, let the user start using the app by fading out the loading screen.

If you need the user to start using the app even before the sounds are loaded, then you can still use the same approach by having a property called "loaded". Remember to keep the handling of this property synchronized.

Comment: I was kind of expecting this since it would be the approach I would usually take in other languages (for IOC etc). I'll have a play and try and implement your suggestion - what I'm looking for is to have the amount of code to do with sound in the view controllers minimal.

Also, please can you explain your last sentence in a bit more detail?

Comment: "Remember to keep the handling of this property synchronized" - means that if you are accessing a resource from several threads, you need to make this thread safe by making sure it is not read and written at the same time. You can do this with @synchronized-blocks or by using atomic properties (not nonatomic) and accessing them always from their getter/setter methods.

Comment: You are definetely on the right track, by trying to keep out the code from the viewcontroller classes. Keeping them minimal saves you a lot of headache and makes your app much easier to maintain, extend and reuse. Keep it up!

Comment: Ok, well I've created ApplicationController as a singleton it init's  SoundManager. VC's can access SoundManager through ApplicationController.

However, I still need to ensure that ApplicationController and all it's associated Managers are full initialised before any VC tries to use it. So I arrive back at the same situation you raised initially - so basically there's little point in pushing the init onto a background thread since it all needs to be loaded before the app can continue anyway, right?

Comment: I suppose that if there are multiple Manager files then I could fire off their initialisation operations concurrently but I still need to wait for everything to have loaded before the app delegate can pass control to the RootVC

Comment: Yes you are totally right, the only reason having the init methods in a background thread is that you will maybe want to show some animations or such things while the user is waiting for the load to complete, and so you maybe don't want to lock the UI thread, but you should in any case make sure that the user don't start using the ViewControllers until everything is loaded properly - you can just let the soundmanager call a method in the ApplicationController when it has finished loading.

Comment: Btw instead of using dispatch_async and stuff I suggest you keep it simple and stick to use the Objective-C methods "performSelectorInBackground" and "perfomeSelectorOnMainThread" to handle threading simply and easy to follow.